# How to Enable I2C of Raspberry Pi3 module (Using with Android Things as an OS)

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, iot, android-things

I am trying to develop a sample **Android-Things** app using Raspberry Pi module 3 which takes temperature reading from **BME280** sensor and display it on app. I have downloaded the sample project but facing an issue while opening I2cDevice with an address.

**Below are the code details:**

private static final int ADDRESS = 0x76;

```
private void printDeviceId() {
    List<String> deviceList = managerService.getI2cBusList();
    if (deviceList.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "No I2C bus available on this device.");
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "List of available devices: " + deviceList);
    }
    I2cDevice device = null;
    try {
        device = managerService.openI2cDevice(deviceList.get(0), ADDRESS);
        Log.d(TAG, "Device ID byte: 0x" + Integer.toHexString(device.readRegByte(0xD0)));
    } catch (IOException|RuntimeException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        try {
            device.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error closing device");
        }
    }
}
```

Actually its crashing on openI2cDevice method while deviceList have only one device i.e. **deviceList.get(0) is "I2C1"**

**Here is the crash log:**
android.os.ServiceSpecificException: I/O error (code 5)
                                                                        com.google.android.things.pio.PioException: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: I/O error (code 5)
                                                                            at com.google.android.things.pio.I2cDeviceImpl.readRegByte(I2cDeviceImpl.java:81)
                                                                            at com.example.pitepmerature.MainActivity.printDeviceId(MainActivity.java:92)
                                                                            at com.example.pitepmerature.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6991)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                                                                         Caused by: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: I/O error (code 5)
                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2018)
                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1950)
                                                                            at com.google.android.things.pio.IPeripheralManagerClient$Stub$Proxy.I2cReadRegByte(IPeripheralManagerClient.java:1301)
                                                                            at com.google.android.things.pio.I2cDeviceImpl.readRegByte(I2cDeviceImpl.java:79)
                                                                            at com.example.pitepmerature.MainActivity.printDeviceId(MainActivity.java:92) 
                                                                            at com.example.pitepmerature.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34) 
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000) 
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6991) 
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)

I tried changing address to 0x77 as well but didn't work. Also gone through many blogs but didn't find the fix.

**Blog link which i preferred to code and setup everything:**

http://zenandroid.io/writing-a-driver-for-android-things-bme280-humidity-sensor/

Please help.

Comment: Try to access to BME280 sensor with [PIO CLI Tool](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/pio-cli.html#I2C): `pio i2c I2C1 0x12 read-reg-byte 0x76`. May be issue is in circuit.

Comment: Also, take a look at [Official Example](https://github.com/androidthings/weatherstation)

Comment: Can you verify that the hardware is connected correctly?

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko: I tried to hit the pio command but got the issue  `rpi3:/ $ pio i2c I2C1 0x12 read-reg-byte 0x76
[WARNING:client_errors.cc(35)] error 5: I/O error`

Comment: Is `I2C1` a valid name? What is `$pio list i2c` response?

Comment: @NickFelker: Could you suggest any specific way to verify the hardware connection with the sensor?

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko: Getting  `I2C1` after checking pio list i2c

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko : Does it means that I2C is enabled?

Comment: Yes, and it's name `I2C1`. Check wire connections.

Comment: Just checking the name in the pio list will not help. If OP has an oscilloscope or logic analyzer, they will be able to verify the signals are coming out of the correct wire.

It is possible they have the Tx and Rx lines switched.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/74492/android-things-i2c-avc-denied/74598#74598) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the helpful comments. I finally found the solution, actually the problem was with the sample I was executing. Also, i have figured-out the correct pin configuration. 
Here is the sample project git link:

https://github.com/androidthings/drivers-samples/tree/master/bmx280

Also, check the pin diagram I followed[image]